# Can I use Pearson's or Spearman's on a Likert-style survey?

Tags: r, correlation, survey, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I am doing a follow up survey to a previous study. It has to do with scientific news stories, seeing if exposure to the news story changes a negative behavior of theirs. For example, exposure to a media story about how misplaced, polluted waste can end up hurting us to see if that will mean people will litter less often.

Can I use one or both of these statistical processes to test for correlation between questions? I would want to compare a question asking if they saw the media story to how likely they are to not litter moving forward, assuming those who saw the news coverage would "strongly agree" that they will not litter in the future based on that media report.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have 500 subjects of whom 200 saw the news story and 300 did not.
Then perhaps you want to know whether Likert scores of the two groups follow
the same probability distributions. That could lead to a chi-squared
test for homogeneity.

Fake data, where Likert-5 means strongly inclined not
to litter. Vector `p` has *proportions,* which R converts to
*probabilities.* (Unless the news story is extremely persuasive, I would not expect to see such strong differences
in your data.)

```
set.seed(2019)
see = sample(1:5, 200, rep=T, p = c(1,1,2,3,5))
a = tabulate(see);  a
[1] 15 13 30 47 95

not = sample(1:5, 300, rep=T, p = c(1,2,2,2,2))
b = tabulate(not);  b
[1] 30 72 76 61 61
```

**Results of chi-squared test of homogeneity.** I programmed a difference---with those who see the report of the study much
more likely to give high Likert responses. This was reflected in counts
with a highly significant difference, with a P-value very near 0.

```
DTA = rbind(a,b)
chisq.test(DTA)

 chisq.test(DTA)

     Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  DTA
X-squared = 57.438, df = 4, p-value = 1.001e-11
```

If you look at the formula for the chi-squared statistic in a statistics
textbook, you will see Observed and Expected counts for this test.
You may also see 'Pearson Residuals'. The sum of the squared residuals
is the chi-squared statistic 57.438. Residual values above 2 may help you understand what features of the data led to rejection of the null
hypothesis that the two groups have similar proportions of responses
in each Likert category.

```
chisq.test(DTA)$obs          # Observed data
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
a   15   13   30   47   95
b   30   72   76   61   61
chisq.test(DTA)$exp          # Expected counts if null hyp True
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
a   18   34 42.4 43.2 62.4
b   27   51 63.6 64.8 93.6
chisq.test(DTA)$resi
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]      [,5]
a -0.7071068 -3.601470 -1.904315  0.5781516  4.126913
b  0.5773503  2.940588  1.554867 -0.4720588 -3.369610
```

In this test, if the null hypothesis were true, we would expect
about 62 Likert-5 scores out of 200 in the group that saw the story and about
94 out of 300 in the group that did not. Instead, we the counts were 95 and 61
(almost reversed). [There is a less extreme discrepancy for Likert-2 scores.]

**Results of (possibly applicable) Wilcoxon test.** If you are willing to treat Likert scores as numerical values (rather than
ordinal categories), then you might use a two-sample Wilcoxon test to
see if the two distributions are the same. You have many ties among the
500 Likert scores, so one may wonder whether the P-value from this Wilcoxon
test is accurate. (With such large sample sizes, many statisticians would
say they are.)  Again here, the P-value is very near 0, so you have
a significant difference between the two groups.

```
summary(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     13      15      30      40      47      95 
summary(b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     30      61      61      60      72      76 

wilcox.test(a,b)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  a and b
W = 6.5, p-value = 0.2477
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(a, b) : 
    cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

*Note:* I do not see a role for correlation here because you do not have pairs of
responses by individuals. You would have such pairs if had Likert scores for each
subject before and after reading the news story.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing such a detailed response, this is incredibly helpful and it makes a lot of sense. If there is not a role for correlation, do you think there would be ultimately one statistical approach to packaging information gained from a Likert survey like this?

Comment: Depends on objective. If you're mainly interested in changes of dist'n of various Likert scores (e.g., from indecisive to decisive), then chi-sq. If mainly interested whether one group has higher scores (e.g., more`strongly favor`s, then Wilcoxon.